# Add Element to Grid and set its Row Windows Phone

Tags: xaml

Lets say you want to add a new element to a Grid with the following code:

```
ExpanderView newExpander = new ExpanderView();
newExpander.Name = name;
newExpander.Header = header;
newExpander.FontSize = 40;

if (row == 0)
    newExpander.IsExpanded = true;

foreach (Item li in items)
{
     CheckBox tb = new CheckBox();
     tb.Content = content;
     tb.FontSize = 20;

     newExpander.Items.Add(tb);
}


MyGrid.Children.Add(newExpander);
Grid.SetRow(newExpander, row);
```

And now the grid in xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
```

Now the last line Grid.SetRow(newExpander, row) in the cs code portion,
How can you tell it which grid you want to set the new row for if you have multiple grids in the .xaml code?

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
Grid.SetRow(newExpander, row);
```

only sets `Grid.Row="1"` if row is 1 in your object properties.

To use this properties the grid that contains the object must have it's `RowDefinitions` set

> How can you tell it which grid you want to set the new row for if you have multiple grids in the .xaml code?

You don't need to tell since the object remains in the Grid in witch you added it.
When you change the Property `Grid.Row` it only sets on witch row of the grid, your control will be rendered

Comment: I see what you are saying for this example.  I guess my question was more generalized for lets say if you had a 4 column by 2 row grid now that I think about it.  I set the children element with the grid name of "MyGrid" but than use the generic "Grid" windows phone control name to set the row or column.  So if I had "MyGrid1", "MyGrid2", "MyGrid3", how would you determine which row or column you were setting for a specific grid by just using "Grid.Row"?

Comment: are you using multiple Grids?

Comment: Yes I am but for the example shown I really do not need to specify the row as each row will only contain one column.  My last question was just a general inquiry in case, during the building process, I run into a design scenario where I want to incorporate multiple columns per row.

Comment: You can check for Parent property to know in which Grid you have added the control you are talking about.